# Issues overriding css :before pseudo element

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm following a tutorial. I was advised to override the background property in css for a hover.css animation, sweep to bottom. This changes the background colour from its original blue to the specified colour.

```
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:before {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
```

When reloading the page, the styling doesn't take effect.

According to the tutorial, the new animation effect should be the newly specified colour. I double and triple checked i had written the code correctly.

When using chrome developer tools, i found the pre-existing :before for the class and can change the colour there, which it will then take effect. The code used in developer tools is no different than mine.

I've tried upping the specificity by adding in the element before it but still no use.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. For us to help you with a problem, please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your question needs to include all the code needed to reproduce the problem, and no more. Edit your question to improve it, and I'm sure we'll be able to help.

Answer (score -1):

scss or less file are watching css file?

then,

search file "_options.scss"

and make "$activeColor" variable

```
$activeColor: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) !default;
```